# radeon_pm_info: What are vclk, dclk, sclk, mclk, vddc and vddci?

Tags: kernel, radeon

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/64/radeon_pm_info
uvd    vclk: 0 dclk: 0
power level 0    sclk: 37500 mclk: 150000 vddc: 950 vddci: 875 pcie gen: 3
```

I'd like to know what are these vclk, dclk, sclk, mclk, vddc, vddci numbers. I guess vddc and vddci are some kind of frequencies in MHz (not sure memory or card), but I really would like to decypher this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **VCLK** and **DCLK** are two [UVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Video_Decoder) internal clocks.
- **SCLK** is the Engine clock and **MCLK** is the Memory clock, both depend on the current power level.
- **VDDC** (mV) is the GPU core voltage
- **VDDCI** (mV) is the I/O bus voltage (between memory and GPU core) and comes from the PCI-Express slot.

Note: clock units seem to be kHz * 10 ([Source](http://git.sysphere.org/vicious/plain/contrib/ati.lua))

Sources:

- [drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_atombios.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_atombios.c#L1228)
- [AMD Radeon HD 6870 Voltage Modifications – The Complete Collection](http://vr-zone.com/articles/amd-radeon-hd-6870-voltage-modifications-the-complete-collection/10211.html)
- [Radeon HD 6870 Voltage Check Points](http://www.geeks3d.com/20101107/radeon-hd-6870-voltage-check-points-vddc-vddci-and-mvdd/)

Comment: I read the documentation you provided, but couldn't figure out what is an unit in sclk? sclk 37500 means 375MHz? and mclk 150000 means 1.5GHz?

Comment: @MladenAdamovic: Units for clock variables are a bit weird. It's kHz * 10. I've found this [code](http://git.sysphere.org/vicious/plain/contrib/ati.lua) which also applies the *10 factor.